# My Home page redirecting too many times after my customer logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have my WordPress site, https://taajisabji.incheaprate.com. There is a problem that after customers logged in, they can access all other pages except the home page. A home page giving Err_too_many_redirects error after logged in. Before logging in, it is works superb.

I have tried everything like, WP URL, Site URL, wp-config.php but it's not working. I think this is some other problem as the error shown only after the customer logged in.

Through the Admin account logged in, the Home page is not redirecting means works well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution of my query.

My homepage was blocked by Ultimate User plugin. I have made some changes like access the home page was unticked and the same I have ticked in Customer User Roles.

Now my problem solved...

If you are facing the same issue, please check the ultimate user plugin first.